# How to create a scratch org with communities enabled?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Given the `project-scratch-def.json`:

```
{
  "orgName": "My Org",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [
    "LiveAgent",
    "AuthorApex",
    "TerritoryManagement",
    "ServiceCloud",
    "Knowledge",
    "Communities"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "orgPreferenceSettings": {
      "networksEnabled": true,
      "s1DesktopEnabled": true,
      "chatterEnabled": true
    },
    "liveAgentSettings": {
      "enableLiveAgent": true
    },
    "communitiesSettings": {
      "enableNetworksEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

And `sfdx-project.json`:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "src", "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "45.0"
}
```

After running this command:

```
force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a org-SCRATCH -v org-DEVHUB -s -d 29
```

I get this error:

> Error  shape/package.xml        The object 'Communities' of type
>   Settings metadata does not exist.

This is weird because [Metadata Coverage report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/47/Network/scratch-def/developer) provides these settings:

```
{
  "orgName": "Sample Org",
  "edition": "developer",
  "features": [
    "COMMUNITIES"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "communitiesSettings": {
      "enableNetworksEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your API version is set to 45.0 (and/or your Dev Hub may not be on Winter '20 yet). On that API version, the `networksEnabled` setting lives in `orgPreferenceSettings`, e.g.,

```
  "features": [
    "Communities"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "orgPreferenceSettings": {
      "networksEnabled": true
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

As of v49.0, there are now force:community commands in sfdx!

[Salesforce CLI Command Reference: community Commands](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_community.htm)